# PHP and short URL

Tags: php, apache, url

I have an URL like this one:

http://www.domain.net/page.php?id=1254

I want to cut my URL (just like url shortners like Bitly or Goo.gl do) this way:

http://www.domain.net/1254

I have no idea about how to do it (a server setting? A PHP setting?), can you point me to some useful reference?

Regards.

Comment: If you are using Apache as a web server - http://htaccess-guide.com/

Comment: @kingkero It lacks sufficient information? Anyone here understood the problem   :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use .htaccess

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ page.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: will it not affect the other urls? like `http://www.domain.net/other.php?id=1`?

Comment: no, because its different file `other.php`. you just need to change `page.php` to `other.php` then it will work for other.php also

Answer (score 1):

You need `mod_rewrite` to replace urls via apache

Documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html